# Find Users without a password in UNIX AIX

Tags: unix, scripting, aix

I'm searching for a script that finds users who don't have a password.

Could anybody please explain me the commands that are needed in such a script?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [logins](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds3/logins.htm) command. The `-p` flag displays users without passwords.

Example usage:

```
# logins -p
```

You can also parse `/etc/security/passwd` and look for an empty password entry.